# WPF - Data Binding Examples

Tags: wpf, binding

I am trying to wrap my arms around WPF binding. I feel like if I can really understand how this works, I can take full advantage of WPF. I recently came across the following, on StackOverflow, that really helped me understand one particular aspect of binding. It is as follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllRoles, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Name="Hello">
```

Which means: "Look at my ancestry until you find a Window, then look for a public property on the window called AllRoles". Bind that to the List.

Does anyone know where I can find more very simple examples with explanations like this? I found this extremely useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WPF Data Binding Cheat Sheet](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nbdtech.com%2FFree%2FWpfBinding.pdf&ei=LMdiTbvwI4mgOtiAobUN&usg=AFQjCNE3Ir6n9W-8twckhUA_c3DuO7Kvdg&sig2=bPsGOBF_wFaQL4oywoHwVg)

This did it for me. It has examples for most aspects of data binding in WPF. I kept a printed copy with me when I was starting with WPF and it really did help.

Though 90% of bindings I use are simple `{Binding Something}` or `{Binding ElementName=someElement}`, it great to know all the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I found Bea Stollnitz's blog to have lots of really useful stuff

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/