# How to actually do Data Binding in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF  I want to  bind my data grid to a table in data base . I am unable to understand the procedure , do I have to specify binding to each column or it can be at once? 
Kindly some one explain clearly how to do that , will be really grateful to you.

Comment: So many duplicates I can't choose one. Let's start with [WPF - Data Binding Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5070738/62576). Google found the [Data Binding Overview at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [WPF Basic Data Binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx).

Comment: I have already go through the text still confuse

Comment: We're not tutors. Those documents explain things pretty clearly, in several different ways. If you can't understand any of them, what makes you think our explaining it yet again will change things for you? Read them again.